# Dynamic "More" tab for a UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I am wondering how I can have a "More" button inside of a segmented control much like how the tab bar works if you add too many tabs. Apple does this in the iTunes app. For example, at the top here:

[image]

Clicking on more brings up a modal table view with a dozen options.

When you switch to Spanish the shown options are reduced by one because of the longer strings. The other option is now just in the modal list when you click on More (Más).

[image]

Is there a way to show a more tab automatically when they tabs can't fit or is Apple manually adjusting the tab count for every single language they support?

Comment: No built-in "more" functionality as with `UITabBar`. As far as iTunes app, it could be specific to language, or on-the-fly calculation of label widths.